# OpenGLES extension in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'd like to use `glBeginQuery(GL_TIME_ELAPSED,query)` in OpenGLES, so I found out that this can be done using this extension: [EXT_disjoint_timer_query](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_disjoint_timer_query.txt) and only OpenGL ES 2.0 or greater is required. My device is a Nexus 4 and I found [here](http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/gles_generatereport.php?reportID=17) that it supports this extension. But when I use `String extensions = GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS);`, I can't see this extension avaiable there. Do you know what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I found out that the SDK has access to a limited subset of OpenGL ES extensions, while the NDK has full access to whatever OpenGL ES extensions a device supports. So to use EXT_disjoint_timer_query I need to use the NDK.